# How run angular universal in production

Tags: angular, express, angular-universal

I have a project which is based on MEAN STACK.

`Front-end`: Angular 6.*.

`Backend`:  ExpressJs and Mongodb.

Locally, angular runs on port `4200` and ExpressJs run on port `3000`.

In production, I build angular and run it as static files fils inside my ExpressJs `app.js`. For example,

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/web/browser/index.html"));
});
```

Currently, I have implemented `Angular Universal` on my existing project after following the documentation.

It works find locally because `Angular Universal` has its own `Node.js® Express` server locally which run on port `4000`.

In production, when I want to run the static files, the `Angular Universal` does show up as expected.

For example, `app.js` after adding universal.

```
let express = require("express");
let path = require("path");

let dotEnv = require("dotenv");
let passport = require("passport");
let app = express();
let server = require("http").Server(app);
dotEnv.load();
let fs = require("fs");
let io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
const appServer = require("./public/web/server/main");

// load intial configuration
require("./startup/initial-configuration")(app, io);
require("./server/config/socket")(io);
require("./server/config/database")(app, process.env.NODE_ENV);
require("./server/authentication/passport.local")(passport);
require("./server/authentication/passport.impersonate");
require("./startup/initial-routes")(app);
require("./server/middleware/custom-middleware")(app);

// angular universal
app.engine('html', ngUniversal.ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: appServer.AppServerModuleNgFactory
}));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/web/index.html"));
});

require("./startup/schedule-jobs")(io);
module.exports = { app: app, server: server };
```

My question is how to add those feature which is in `server.ts` files int `app.js` file of expressJS.

I have searched a lot, but I could not found any solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a handler for your static files. As such, I add a handler for any file that has a `.` in it that is contained in my output directory, "dist/browser", which is the client-side of the Angular application generated by the build process:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

const app = express();
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

. . .

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));
```

I would *highly* recommend following the Universal Guide: https://angular.io/guide/universal as a starting point, then add any functionality on top of that once your Angular app is working as expected.

If you have an existing Node.js app written in JavaScript and you're wanting to add this functionality on top of it, there's really no reason to write the Universal side of the Angular app in TypeScript, if you don't need to.

Your build process should be doing the TypeScript to JavaScript transpilation of the Angular app, but the server.js file itself, or rather the functionality of it can be just plain JavaScript, provided it accomplishes the same thing.